# Lapsed Advanced Ground Instructor certificate, can I take a FIRC and and restore my privileges?

Tags: faa-regulations, ground-instructor

I hold an AGI certificate that I haven't exercised the privileges for in quite some time (more than 12 calendar months).

According to [14 CFR 61.217](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.217), can I simply take a Flight Instructor Refresher Course (online or in person) and restore my [privileges](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.215)?

> § 61.217 Recent experience requirements. The holder of a ground
>   instructor certificate may not perform the duties of a ground
>   instructor unless the person can show that one of the following
>   occurred during the preceding 12 calendar months:
>
> (a) Employment or activity as a ground instructor giving pilot, flight
>   instructor, or ground instructor training;
>
> (b) Employment or activity as a flight instructor giving pilot, flight
>   instructor, or ground instructor ground or flight training;
>
> (c) Completion of an approved flight instructor refresher course and
>   receipt of a graduation certificate for that course; or
>
> (d) An endorsement from an authorized instructor certifying that the
>   person has demonstrated knowledge in the subject areas prescribed
>   under § 61.213(a)(3) and (a)(4), as appropriate.

It appears so, but I guess at the root of my question is, is it really that simple or did I miss a regulation or sign-off requirement somewhere (I know I could get signed off in leiu of the FIRC).

Then to keep current, what constitutes `activity as a ground instructor giving pilot...training`?  Just teaching and logging that I've been teaching ground school, or would I actually have had to endorse some people to take the written exam during those 12 calendar months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as the regulation says, you can indeed take an FIRC to restore your privileges.

Second, I couldn't find any FAA clarification on exactly what "employment or activity as a ground instructor" means, but the language is fairly clear: you just have to be able to show that you were providing instruction as a ground instructor. That could be via training records, invoices, employment contracts, written test endorsements etc.

As a general rule, there's no need to look for extra requirements that aren't stated in the regulations.

Comment: `As a general rule, there's no need to look for extra requirements that aren't stated in the regulations.` Hah! Yeah, that is for sure, its more that this one just seemed too straight-forward.